# IE11,can't get the arguments of a function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

for example, like this function:

```
function foo(){
   console.log(arguments)
}
foo(1,2,3);
```

normally,we will get '[1,2,3]' in console,

But at IE11 in win7,when we change the doc mode to IE7 ~ IE9,
we just get 'undefind' instead.

I want to know why? and how can I get the  The Unknown Quantity arguments?

Comment: Works fine (well, I see `[object Arguments]` because IE's dev tools still suck) on IE11 on Windows 8.1.  Did you remember to open the console *before* (re-)loading the page?  If the console isn't open, then `window.console` doesn't exist.  Also, try `console.dir(arguments)`.

Comment: If you do `console.log(arguments.length);`, it works. I guess this is an emulating bug only, real IE7 - 9 would give you expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this in the console and I get two things first undefined which is the result of the function not returning anything and then I get [object Arguments] which is of course the logging of the arguments object.  Try this to see if it changes the undefined

```
function foo(){
   console.log(arguments);
   return 'Hello world';
}
foo(1,2,3);
```

[image]